# Getting rid of Characters in CVS file to get mean of columns

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, python-3.x

I asked for help a while ago and I thought this was what I was looking for unfortunately I ran into another problem. In my CSV file I have ?'s inplace of missing data in some rows in the 13 columns. I have an idea of how to fix it but have yet to be successful in implementing it. My current Idea would be to use use ord and chr to change the ? to 0 but not sure how to implement that to list. This is the error I get

```
File "C:\Users\David\Documents\Python\asdf.py", line 46, in <module>
    iList_sum[i] += float(ill_data[i])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?'
```

Just so you know I can not use numby or panda. I am also trying to refrain from using mapping since I am trying to get a very simplistic code.

```
import csv

#turn csv files into a list of lists
with open('train.csv','rU') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     csv_data = list(reader)

# Create two lists to handle the patients
# And two more lists to collect the 'sum' of the columns
# The one that needs to hold the sum 'must' have 0 so we 
# can work with them more easily
iList = []
iList_sum = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

hList = []
hList_sum = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

# Only use one loop to make the process mega faster
for row in csv_data:
    # If row 13 is greater than 0, then place them as unhealthy
    if (row and int(row[13]) > 0):
        # This appends the whole 'line'/'row' for storing :)
        # That's what you want (instead of saving only one cell at a time)
        iList.append(row)

    # If it failed the initial condition (greater than 0), then row 13
    # is either less than or equal to 0. That's simply the logical outcome
    else:
        hList.append(row)

# Use these to verify the data and make sure we collected the right thing
# print iList
# [['67', '1', '4', '160', '286', '0', '2', '108', '1', '1.5', '2', '3', '3', '2'], ['67', '1', '4', '120', '229', '0', '2', '129', '1', '2.6', '2', '2', '7', '1']]
# print hList
# [['63', '1', '1', '145', '233', '1', '2', '150', '0', '2.3', '3', '0', '6', '0'], ['37', '1', '3', '130', '250', '0', '0', '187', '0', '3.5', '3', '0', '3', '0']]

# We can use list comprehension, but since this is a beginner task, let's go with basics:

# Loop through all the 'rows' of the ill patient 
for ill_data in iList:

    # Loop through the data within each row, and sum them up
    for i in range(0,len(ill_data) - 1):
        iList_sum[i] += float(ill_data[i])


# Now repeat the process for healthy patient
# Loop through all the 'rows' of the healthy patient 
for healthy_data in hList:

    # Loop through the data within each row, and sum them up
    for i in range(0,len(healthy_data) - 1):
        hList_sum[i] += float(ill_data[i])

# Using list comprehension, I basically go through each number
# In ill list (sum of all columns), and divide it by the lenght of iList that
# I found from the csv file. So, if there are 22 ill patients, then len(iList) will
# be 22. You can see that the whole thing is wrapped in brackets, so it would show
# as a python list

ill_avg = [ ill / len(iList) for ill in iList_sum]
hlt_avg = [ hlt / len(hList) for hlt in hList_sum]
```

Here is a screenshot of the CSV file.
[image: CSV file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check the value you get from the list:

```
# Loop through the data within each row, and sum them up
qmark_counter = 0
for i in range(0,len(ill_data) - 1):
    if ill_data[i] == '?':
        val = 0
        qmark_counter += 1
    else
        val = ill_data[i]
    iList_sum[i] += float(val)
```

And so on for the other ones. There are many other improvements that could be done; for instance, I would put the snippet of code in a function so that it does not have to be repeated multiple times.

EDIT: added the counter for question marks. If you want to keep track of question marks separately for each list, you may want to use a dictionary.

Comment: ok and if I wanted to ad a separate counter for the ?'s would I put it under val? or would I have to make a new if statement?

Comment: Added a simple counter for question marks in the answer.